# Jenkins/Maven build throws 'Access is denied' error for surefire-reports .html and .xml files

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build

Jenkins/Maven build throws 'Access is denied' error for surefire-reports index.html; .xml files even though the folder/file permissions granted full access.

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Jenkins\workspace\MySample_Jenkins\target\surefire-reports\html\index.html (Access is denied)

Comment: The jerkins agent that builds would not have permission user you used to try it with might have them.

Comment: I have permission in Jenkins to build but still having the same issue.

Comment: I often had this issue using cygwin and java tools. As you are using windows, try to right-click your C:\jenkins folder and go to the Access & Security tab. Check if the jenkins user has access on all directories. Re-set the permissions and check "recursively" apply. Did this help?